# How to add WordPress User Role to Woocommerce New Admin Order Email Subject

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The Woocommerce website I am building has user roles for retail customers and wholesale customers.  I would like to add the User Role as part of the New Order Admin Email Subject Line so that the customer service department will be able to determine which type of order it is.  Right now the subject is "[Company Name] New customer order (22315) - August 20, 2018".

I would like it to be "[Company Name] New  customer order (22315) - August 20, 2018" where  is the user role that get's pulled from WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

**here you go :**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'change_admin_email_subject', 1, 2);
function change_admin_email_subject($subject, $order)
{
    $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);
    $user_roles = $user->roles;

    if (in_array('administrator', $user_roles, true)) { //Here you can defind which role do want of course

        $role = 'administrator';
    } else {
        $role = 'Customer';
    }

    $subject = sprintf('[%s] New Customer Order (%s)  role %s %s', $blogname, $order->id, $role, wc_format_datetime($order->get_date_created()));
    return $subject;

}
```

put this code in your `functions.php`

This code is test and working.